# Download a file from any given URL and save it to my Machine with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, file, download

**Case:** I need to feed my application a URL from any location on the internet.  At the other end of the URL will be a file of some sorts.  A picture/video/document and I need to save this item to my server automatically **without** a 'save-as' dialog box.

This needs to be done in ASP.NET.

Im having trouble on how to actually grab that file with asp.net after feeding it a URL...  Any help would be great!

Thanks all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use webclient or httpwebrequest. Webclient is probably easier for what you want to do.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();

wc.DownloadFile(downloadURL.Text, savePath.Text);
```

Answer (score 8):

I'd check out the [System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class.  The [DownloadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144194.aspx) method should do the trick for you.

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.DownloadFile(myUrl, myLocalFileName);
}
```

Just make sure that the user that your web app is running as has permissions to save the file or you'll have problems.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx